# Ошибка name 'filter_tags' is not defined. Многоклассовая классификация

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

Пробую сделать многоклассовую классификацию, в одном из мануалов написано:

`tags = texts.tags.apply(lambda x: x.split())
 all_tags = reduce(lambda s, x: s + x, tags, [])
 values, count = np.unique(all_tags, return_counts=True)
 top_tags = sorted(zip(count, values), reverse=True)[:20]`

Затем: Преобразуем списки тегов в матрицу, которая будет содержать
индикаторы наличия тега у вопроса. С помощью следующего кода:

`binarizer = MultiLabelBinarizer()
2 y = binarizer.fit_transform(texts.tags.apply(lambda x:
filter_tags(x.split())))`

И вот тут уже возникает ошибка! Как ее решить?
Если что, мануал тут: http://www.machinelearning.ru/wiki/images/6/64/Mel_lain_msu_nlp_sem_3.pdf , стр. 22

Comment: _Как ее решить?_ - определить  функцию `filter_tags`.

Answer (score 0):

```
filter_tags(x.split())
```

Это функция `filter_tags()`. Она должна быть где-то определена ранее в виде `def filter_tags(x):`

У вас она нигде не определена. Поэтому код выдает ошибку, что ничего не знает про эту функцию.